# WFH outside of your assigned country

Tags: remote-work

I will appreciate some help on my case. Our company's offices (UK based) have been shut from Spring 2020 and will continue to be shut until Jan 2021. We are officially WFH as per guidance.

Myself and my partner haven't been home (country outside of the EU) for almost two years due to covid restrictions and banned flights. We have arrived to our home country to renew some of our documents and to spend time with relatives (we also lost some relatives to covid). Myself and my partner requested to WFH for a month from our home country, and she got a green light from her employer, and I only got a permission for 10 days, which is not enough, and was requested to return to the UK. We are already abroad from the UK. Additionally, my partner is aerophobic and won't fly without me.

I need to mention that I am a full citizen in both countries. I feel bad about not being able to WFH and spend time with my family in that way, given all we had to go through.

What are my rights and options in that case, as I would like to stay longer (without taking a leave of absence).

Thanks,
SR

Comment: This will depend on the exact details of your contract, and nobody here can tell you how any clauses there will be interpreted given the pandemic. Talk to a lawyer - although if I were your employer, I would be _very_ unhappy if I found you had travelled with the intent of not returning within the agreed 10 days.

Comment: Philip, thanks for your response. I have left the UK for holiday first of all and then we decided to stay longer. Also, I was not aware of the need to request permission to work from another country for a couple of weeks, since it was not the case previously and a few of my colleagues did so throughout the year.

Comment: My employer has recently issued some guidance around this as there is a number of tax implications when working outside the UK over the course of the year, and not just the period in question. We are restricted to 30 days in the tax year for that purpose. It is likely that timescale requested will form part of the response

Answer (score 8):

There have recently been issues at my workplace, with staff who have been working abroad recalled to the country. The resulting discussions highlighted a number of issues around payroll, tax and employment law which mean that while not impossible to allow a member of staff to work from another country besides the UK, it is very difficult and time consuming to set up. You have been lucky to even get 10 days, we now have a blanket ban.

Your choices are to either take leave or return to the UK. If you're very lucky you may be able to negotiate with your employer to get an extra two weeks, but I'd just take leave if I were you.

Comment: Other aspects are security, and for the employee maintaining their immigration status. With pre-settled status in the UK, being outside the country for more than six months in any one-year period usually makes it impossible to receive settled status, which means five years after getting pre-settled status you will have to leave.